# universal politics of alien warfare

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, science-fiction, warfare, politics

My story is a space adventure, opera, and war with an advanced alien race going to war with each other using this [magic] [1] system plus FTL, iron stars, and Dyson spheres, but as I was world-building, I realized I had no idea what the warfare actually looks like in my setting or how to incorporate the magic system into battles. So my question is, "What does warfare look like when many competing political interests are involved?" More importantly, how do I build the inscrutability of the aliens and their politics while keeping everything clear? It would help me greatly if you gave me some ideas.
[1]: https://docs.google.com/document/d/107fac0oChtUipvy6KxOz7ue4GBQE1SXt_sqj9ElHieg/edit

Comment: This question is unanswerable without much more information.  Some of the most obvious are:  What are the objectives of the warring factions? Conquest and extermination will be conducted very differently.  How does FTL work and what are its limits?  What are the characteristics of the warring factions in terms of capabilities, size, unity of purpose?  What information technology is available?  Without knowing this, there is no way to judge whether "warfare" is all stars of one faction going nova simultaneously in a first strike or low-level cyber attacks and propaganda warfare.

Comment: This seems very broad and unfocused at present. It seems to ask for (potentially) what could become books and books for answers, this doesn't fit our site's format well. Please see our [catalogue of question types](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types), to see what sort of questions are on and off topic here. Haven't you already asked this and then deleted it once, without changing it much?

Comment: I think he did it hat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re just asking for examples of many-party wars, I can give you a few from history:

Allies, Geographically Isolated : examples of this would be Russia’s place among the Allied nations, or Germany, Italy and Japan among the Axis in World War 2. These nations are working for a common cause, but not sharing much else. They are fighting largely on their own.

Allies, Geographically Mixed : this would be the British in France during WW2, or the Americans and British in France during WW1 or the Americans in England during WW2 or even that tiny bit of boots on the ground support America gave Russia during WW1 and WW2. These soldiers are sharing personnel, material, and working out of the same bases and fields, and may be under the same joint command structure at the top levels.

Allies, Conquered : you could think of this as the French Resistance, or Polish during WW2 or the Russians during the Seige of Stalingrad. They are contributing in a small, but sometimes enormously significant way.

Supporters, Isolated : this could be the US during WW1 and early WW2. These are people sending supplies and equipment. They have no fear of being forced into the conflict because they are so far away, and can contribute with a certain degree of aloofness.

Supporters, Nearby : this could be the Arab nations supporting Saladin against the Crusaders. Or Iraq’s support of the Axis in WW2. By offering support, they took a substantial risk to getting drawn into the conflict.

Enemies with an Enemy in Common : China going to war with Japan during WW2 helped the Allied cause by creating a front to keep the Empires attention. Maybe also Russia (originally an Axis power until invaded by Germany). Their contributions to the allies cause are an accidental overlap, not deliberate.

Locals, Allied with One Party : this could be the cargo islanders to the extent that they helped either the Americans or Japanese.